# How to refresh / reload / completely close and reopen jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've read the similar questions regarding this problem, tried few methods but none is working.

I have 2 JFrame forms. I want to input information in the first form and submit it to the database. When I click a button, the second form will open and load the information
When I re-input new information in the first form and click the the button again, I want the second form to reload the new information inputted from the database.
This is my code so far.

```
time t = new time();
private void OrderButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

if(t.isVisible()){
    t.dispose();
    t.revalidate();
    t.repaint();
    t.setVisible(true);
    t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }

 else{
    t.setVisible(true);
    t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }
```

Comment: @Toaster the first form is gonna be used by user to input data

Comment: Then which from you wanna close? Well, take data from the 1st form and update it  to the second form

Comment: i want to update the second form, and how to do it is by closing and reopening the form. Sorry is my question not clear enough ?

Comment: Hmm, I can't understand what do you want to do. Do you want just to update or make it invisible and visisble

Comment: You can directly change the values of `JLabel` or etc things. You don't need to make a mess with frames . You can check this project by : https://github.com/ExploiTR/Login-Windows/blob/master/src/main/java/exploitr/MainView.java

Comment: when the user input something in first form and click button, it will appear in the second form's label. when the user re-input something in the first form and click the button again, second's form label will be updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174871/discussion-between-toaster-and-kevin-guswanto).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to play with JFrames for that. See below example :

```
JLabel toe = new JLabel("I'm primary text");
JFrame cow = new JFrame("Primary Window");
JPanel cowpanel = new JPanel();
cowpanel.add(toe);
cow.setContentPane(cowpanel);
cow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
cow.pack();
cow.setVisible(true);
JButton tow = new JButton("Change");
tow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        toe.setText("Hi!, I'm secondary text!");
    }
});
JFrame dog = new JFrame("Secondary Window");
JPanel dogPanel = new JPanel();
dog.setContentPane(dogPanel);
dogPanel.add(tow);
dog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
dog.pack();
dog.setVisible(true);
```

Clicking the 'Change' button from Frame 2 will change the `JLabel`'s text in Frame 1.